# Unable to extract routes from application while pre rendering angular app

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm trying to implement pre rendering in angular app version 11.

After running the command  `npm run prerender` I'm getting the below error

```
Unable to extract routes from application.
```

My App Module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule),
  }
];
```

PagesModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./home-page/home-page.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'tariff',
        component: TariffComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        component: ContactComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I created a `routes.txt` file and added the following lines

```
/about
/traiff
/contact
```

In angular.json file,

```
    "prerender": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "newTaxi:build:production",
        "serverTarget": "newTaxi:server:production",
        "routesFile": "./routes.txt"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {}
      }
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong here ? please guide me

Comment: Have you found what was the issue with prerendering, I faced exactly same issue now.

Comment: Seems related to this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1769), about lazy-loading